# VBA Updating table from multiple sources - incorrect data saved

Tags: ms-access, vba

My database needs the ability to mass import data from multiple sources and merge into existing records if they exist and add new if they do not.

Problem lies with the source data, a lot of the field types do not match the values the same fields have within the database. (Example all 'Location' in the excel documents will be text, within the database 'Location' is numerical)

To counteract this I have basically made 2 new tables. 'Importer' & 'Cleaned'

Importer is loaded into a continuous form and the field controls within the form then do a little magic to convert the text values to numerical. The issue I'm having is getting my code to run and input the required data into Cleaned.

I've tried the following various iterations on the new record line

```
myR2![EventID] = Me.EventIDUpdater.Value
```

```
myR2![EventID] = [Forms]![adf_AttendeeImport]![EventIDUpdater]
```

```
myR2![EventID] = [Forms]![adf_AttendeeImport]![EventIDUpdater].[Value]
```

None of which have the desired effect.

I went through the code line-by-line using breakpoints, nothing came from it.

Below is the full code (This works for another more advanced merge existing/add new import)

```
Private Sub MergeAttendees_Click()

Dim myR As Recordset
Dim myR2 As Recordset

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_STG_AttendeeImport", dbOpenDynaset)
Set myR2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_STG_AttendeeValueUpdater", dbOpenDynaset)

MsgBox prompt:="You are about to convert multiple values, this could take some time. Please allow the process to complete before closing the window/database", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Conversion Warning"

Do Until myR.EOF = True
        myR2.AddNew
        myR2![Email] = myR![Email]
        myR2![TicketAmount] = myR![TicketAmount]
        myR2![Price] = myR![Price]
        myR2![Paid] = myR![Paid]
        myR2![EventID] = Me.EventIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![AttendeeTypeID] = Me.AttendeeTypeIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![PackageID] = Me.PackageIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![TicketTypeID] = Me.TicketTypeIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![DiscountID] = Me.DiscountIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![MethodID] = Me.MethodIDUpdater.Value
        myR2![ConfirmationID] = Me.ConfirmationIDUpdater.Value
        myR2.Update
    myR.MoveNext
Loop

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AttendeeImport")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("del_AttendeeImport")

Me.Requery

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox prompt:="Update Complete - Staging Table Cleared", buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Update Complete"

End Sub
```

I do get the confirmation "Update Complete - Staging Table Cleared" per the msgbox line just before the sub ends. And data is saved into the table however I've noticed the data saved is incorrect (Most likely due to the way I'm getting said data as all records are saving the data of the first fields in the repeated form)

What I need it to do is read down the form correctly and save the data.

Comment: What happens if you add `myR2.Update` to the line just before `myR.MoveNext` and then run that revised code?

Comment: Well, that solved the issue why it wasn't saving any of the data. Can't believe I missed something that stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opted against VBA and form control data to complete what is needed and instead set up several update queries joined on the relevant table to update the values back into the staging table and then used VBA to run the queries in succession.

After the values were updated I used a final upend query to add/update the correct values into the right table and added this to VBA code also.

```
Private Sub ConvertValues_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_ConfirmID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_DiscountID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_EventID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_GuestID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_MethodID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_PackageID")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AVI_TicketID")

Me.Requery

DoCmd.OpenQuery ("upd_AttendeeImport")
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("del_AttendeeImport")

Me.Requery

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```